# How to store the relation between tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I created a table in relation to two other tables, however I do not know how to relate them when creating new projects, how could I do that?

I'll create the categories in a separated page in my admin, and when the user create's a new project he will be able to select an array of categories coming from the table.

My question is, how can I store the relation when `POST` the data? I've never done this before.

Project model

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'projects';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'header',
        'desc',
        'about',
        'url',
        'status'
    ];

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Category model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'status'
    ];

    public function subCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class);
    }

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class);
    }
}
```

My actual Post create

```
public function postCreate(ProjectCreateRequest $request, Customer $customer)
{

    //Array
    $categories = $request->categories;

    $customer->projects()->create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'header' => $request->header,
        'desc' => $request->desc,
        'about' => $request->about,
        'url' => $request->url,
    ]);

    //How do I store the relation?

    return redirect('admin/clientes/editar/' . $customer->id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `attach` or `sync` for many to many relationships
reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models

```
public function postCreate(ProjectCreateRequest $request, Customer $customer)
{
    //Array
    $categories = $request->categories;

    $projects = $customer->projects()->create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'header' => $request->header,
        'desc' => $request->desc,
        'about' => $request->about,
        'url' => $request->url,
    ]);

    //suppose here the $categories is an array of ids or a single integer variable id of the category that are related
    $projects->categories()->attach($categories);

    return redirect('admin/clientes/editar/' . $customer->id);
}
```

Comment: Worked! Another question, how can I get the data from the pivot table?

Comment: $project->categories()->get();

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::category()

Comment: categories() not category()

Comment: post a question with your code. :) need to see the code

Comment: public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->withPivot('pivot_table_column1', 'bar', 'blabla');
    }

Comment: Solved this problem, now I can show data, but a new question come up, I've made a new question...

Answer (score 0):

**First:** Make sure you have the following table in the database in order for the many to many relationship to work

table name : category_project

columns: category_id, project_id

**Second:** class Project needs only the following function for categories relation to work:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

**Third:** class Category needs only the following function for projects relation to work:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class);
}
```

**Fourth:** postCreate function should be as follow:

```
public function postCreate(ProjectCreateRequest $request, Customer $customer)
{

//should be an array of categories ids
$categories = $request->categories;

$project = $customer->projects()->create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'header' => $request->header,
    'desc' => $request->desc,
    'about' => $request->about,
    'url' => $request->url,

]);

//How do I store the relation? you can use attach or sync
$project->categories()->sync($categories);

return redirect('admin/clientes/editar/' . $customer->id);
}
```